# How to iterate javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport in wlst

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

How do you iterate a array of javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport?

```
myBean = ObjectName('com.oracle.sdp.messaging:Location=my_soa_server,name=EmailDriverConfig,type=SDPMessagingDriverConfig,Application=usermessagingdriver-email')

driverParams = mbs.getAttribute(myBean,'DriverParameterProperties')
for param in driverParams:
  ####How to do iterate and do an if on a name#####
    print param.getName()
```

If I do something like this I am getting..

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
AttributeError: getName
```

I have verified that when you execute driverParams[0] that I am getting something like this

```
javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Property,items=((itemName=allowedValues,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.ArrayType(name=[Ljavax.management.openmbean.CompositeData;,dimension=1,elementType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=AllowedValue,items=((itemName=label,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.String)))),primitiveArray=false)),(itemName=description,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.String)),(itemName=encodedCredential,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.String)),(itemName=mandatory,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.String)),(itemName=name,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.String)),(itemName=type,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.String)))),contents={allowedValues=[], description=Supported Delivery Types, encodedCredential=false, mandatory=yes, name=SupportedDeliveryTypes, type=java.lang.String, value=EMAIL})
```

Looking at the attribute, I would like to validate the SupportedDeliveryTypes value

```
name=SupportedDeliveryTypes
value=EMAIL
description=Supported Delivery Types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CompositeDataSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/CompositeDataSupport.html) is not an array.

To view its content you can try using `toString()` (in your sample `driverParams[0].toString()`) or access values with `values()` or `get(String key)` / `getAll(String[] keys)`.

For example, try with:

```
myBean = ObjectName('com.oracle.sdp.messaging:Location=my_soa_server,name=EmailDriverConfig,type=SDPMessagingDriverConfig,Application=usermessagingdriver-email')

driverParams = mbs.getAttribute(myBean,'DriverParameterProperties')
for param in driverParams:
    print param.toString()
```